# How do I count zeros in sublists?

Tags: counting

I have an array RandomInteger[1,{100,100}]. How do I count zeros in each sublist so that I have a list which gives the number of zeros of each sublist in the array?

Comment: `100-Total[your_array_here,{2}]`

Comment: @ciao: Very cute solution! Thanks.

Comment: @Garfield it is not just cute though: it is lightning-fast too! It is pretty much guaranteed to beat any `Map` based solution by orders of magnitude in execution time. Of course you could generalize it as `Length[array] - Total[array, {2}]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another method (also reasonably general?)

```
0 /.(Counts/@myArray)
```

Comment: Or, as a slight alternative to the neat method given by @ciao in a comment `Total[1-mylist,{2}]` (which is independent of array dimensions).

Comment: Thanks for the accept.  IMO a great answer was given in a comment by ciao. You _are_ allowed answer your own question (and accept it as best and(?) up-vote it), and @J. M.'s technical difficulties (moderator) often encourages it.  Maybe post an answer yourself incorporating this answer and the two modifications suggested in the comments, where it will 'jump out' at future visitors? IMO it is a pity that a 'power-tool' answer is 'buried' in the comments. Your question has the potential of attracting a lot of 'hits' from users with the very same query.

Answer (score 7):

Try this example

```
matrix=RandomInteger[1,{5,5}]
```

returns this

```
{{0,1,0,1,1},{0,1,0,0,1},{1,0,1,0,1},{1,1,1,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0}}
```

and then this

```
Map[Count[#,0]&,matrix]
```

returns

```
{2,3,2,2,4}
```

Comment: Note that you can write `Map[Count[0], matrix]` as well, using the operator form. (+1)

Comment: If a likely brand new user doesn't know about `Map` then I try to give them one simple broadly applicable idea for their first time. I understand, and usually mention but didn't this time, that there are almost always at least six different ways of doing anything in Mathematica AND that at least two of those are nearly completely incomprehensible to even moderately experienced users. And I understand that shaving a few seconds or even milliseconds off the run time is some people's only goal in life, far outweighing understandable methods that can be used to solve other problems in the future.

Comment: I agree with the readability and simplicity argument. In fact, it was with those in mind that I proposed the operator form. The two forms are perfectly equivalent and have no difference in execution time but, in my opinion at least, I find the latter more readable than the pure function format, and just as general.